# How can I bring a Very anxious cat to see the vet?

Tags: senior-pet

My furry friend is a  17 yr old indoor cat & apart from when she was neutered many many moons ago (16 and a half yrs precisely) she has never been to vets or put in a cat carrier. She has never liked been picked up preferring to come to me whenever she chooses & not the other way around. She has started toileting outside the box & is giving me other signs of a much-needed check-up. I cannot imagine how I'm going to actually get her in the carrier. Even after reading some good tips, I know it is going to be a  traumatic event taking her out of her 17year comfort zone & im afraid the anxiety might be too over=whelming at her age. I feel a mild sedative pre-journey would be sufficient in her case. Is their such a thing over the counter? Or do vets recommend /issue anything I  could acquire for her before they examine her? Thank you in advance for any advice

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Because a very similar question was already answered here, your question was voted to close with a link to this similar question. If the answers there do not adress your problem, please edit your question and explain how it is different from the linked question :) If your question adresses a new point, it will not be closed.

Comment: For the sedativum mqybe this question will help you: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/28773/is-there-a-way-to-safely-tranquilize-my-cat-so-he-does-not-remember-a-vet-visit?r=SearchResults